# Is there a way from preventing other ReportViewers on the same webpage from refreshing?

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, reportviewer

Currently I am working on a web page that has six [ReportViewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.reportviewer(VS.80).aspx) controls that are using remote processing and that allow for drill-down. When a user clicks on one control the entire page refreshes and the other five reports all refresh as well. Users are currently requesting that the refreshing of the other controls be removed in favor of only the one they click on refreshing. Is there a way of doing this, I've noticed that in Sharepoint that clicking a drill-down report does not require the entire entire page to be reloaded and I'm wondering if I can provide the same functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been doing some more research on this issue and it looks like the [AsyncRendering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252090(VS.80).aspx) property of the ReportViewer control controls the functionality that I'm looking for. When it is set to "false" it prevents the "Report is Being Generated" message from being displayed which is what the users were commenting on. The downside is that the page can take a bit longer to load than before, but as we are working on a development machine this might not be as noticeable once we move to the actual production box.

Comment: Yes, that should do the trick for you. I deleted my answer, as this post reminded me that the AsyncRendering property automatically does what I was saying to do manually. AsyncRendering=True uses an iframe w/no full page postbacks, instead of using inline HTML, which does cause postbacks.